# default profile picture pic helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, profile

I am stuck on a helper method for rendering a default profile picture if one is not set on sign up. Let say I have a helper method like so:

```
def blank_image (user)
  base_image = ""
  if @user.image.empty?
    base_image
  else
    @user.image
  end
end
```

what I need is the url to point `base_image` to so I know where to save this image. I am guessing assets/images but I don't know how to "spell out" the image location if that makes any sense. and also how can I implement this in my view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def blank_image.url(user)
  if @user.image.empty?
    "/assets/default_photo.jpg"
  else
    @user.image.url
  end
end
```

The images on the assets, once they are precompiled, they will be available from /assets (same with stylesheets and javascripts), the "/images" path is removed.

---

Based on your new comment, the best solution may be to provide a default_url for Carrierwave, if you check the [documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave), you can do something like:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [280, 280]
  end

  version :small_thumb, :from_version => :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [20, 20]
  end   

  def default_url
    "/assets/default_images/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

And then on your /app/assets/images/default_images/ you should add the photos create the file **default.png** which is the default image, **thumb_default.png** which is the version :thumb, and finally **small_thumb_default.png** which is the version :small_thumb.

notice that both :thumb and :small_thumb is an example in case you process different image versions for the image uploaded.

Comment: If that helped, I would appreciate that you select my answer as accepted and a positive vote, that improves my reputation. Thx

Comment: Tried this but the image always breaks :-( i am using carrierwave for uploads btw.

Comment: Ok, so your idea is to upload a default image by carrierwave if the user doesn't submit a image... I put some code in order to show a default image on the views if the user didn't submited a image, which makes a little more sense since you may change later carrierwave to paperclip, or you may want to change the default picture for users and if you associated the default picture to the user, then it won't be easy to do such a change later.

Comment: Hello just to clarify this default image goes into the app/assets directory not the public/assets directory.? whenever i put an image in any of these directories it always finds a way or deleting itself :-S i just dont get it. any thoughts?

Comment: It goes into the /app/assets/images/default_images/... You shouldn't get those files deleted, carrierwave actually doesn't have a way to delete files that are within your assets.

Comment: keeps deleting the file just dont get it :-(. Thanks for your help ill keep trying.

Comment: nope, that won't delete your files, make your files read only and try again, then you will probably get an exception when running the process and you will be able to figure out who is deleting your files and why

Comment: Any ideas? Just wondering if i will have to call on default_url in my view ?

Comment: the default_url is a fallback when the user didn't uploaded a photo, in that case it will hit the default_url which will provide the route to the default photos, you can try to put the photos directly into the public directoy (instead of the assets), but you told me that for some reason CarrierWave is deleting them, which is kind of weird that Carrierwave does that. If its an academin/public project, you can try to give me access and I can help with the debug, my username on github is rorra.

Comment: Thanks for you help and all the prompt replies. If i cant solve it soon i will find you on github. Cheers Rorra.